# How to solve integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a solution in *Wolfram, but I don't understand secant? Anybody can help me?

$$\int \sqrt{3x^2+10x+9}\ dx$$
[How I get sec??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR0Vh.png)

Comment: sec(x) = 1/cos(x)

Comment: @Bye_World later on in the integration the integral of sec^3(x) must be computed

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by not understanding the secant.  What step in the solution process do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$3x^2+10x+9=3 (x^2+10/3 x+3) $$

$$=3 \Bigl [(x+5/3)^2-25/9+3\Bigr]$$

$$=2/3\Bigl [\left(\frac {3x+5}{\sqrt {2}}\right)^2+1\Bigr] $$

now put $$3x+5=\sqrt {2}\sinh (u) $$

and use
$$1+\sinh^2=\cosh^2$$

Answer (score 0):

set $$\sqrt{3x^2+10x+9}=\sqrt{3}x+t$$ then we get $$x=\frac{t^2-9}{10-2\sqrt{3}t}$$ and $$dx=1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {3} \left( 10\,\sqrt {3}t-3\,{t}^{2}-27 \right) }{
 \left( -3\,t+5\,\sqrt {3} \right) ^{2}}}dt
$$

Comment: why the $-1$? this is the Euler substtution

Comment: I imagine because if one weren't used to Euler substitutions it looks like all you've done is made the integrand much more complicated.  But here's a +1 to even you out.  Edit: Well that $0$ didn't last long.  Sorry, mate.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start this is to complete the square under the radical:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{3x^2+10x+9} &= \sqrt{3\left(x^2+\frac{10}{3}x+3\right)}\\
&=\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{\left(x+\frac53\right)^2+\frac29}
\end{align}$$

You can now do use the substitution $u=x+\frac53$, and the integral becomes:

$$\sqrt3\int\sqrt{u^2+\frac29}\,\,du$$

Now, follow the usual trig substitution rule, and let $u=\frac{\sqrt2}{3}\tan t$, transforming the integral again into:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt3\int\sqrt{\frac29\left(\tan^2 t + 1\right)}\cdot\sec^2t\,\,dt &= \frac{\sqrt6}{3}\int\sqrt{\sec^2 t}\cdot\sec^2t\,\,dt\\
&= \frac{\sqrt6}{3}\int\sec^3t\,\,dt
\end{align}$$

Now, integrating $\sec^3 t$ is a [whole other story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed), but this gets you that far. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, now is so much easier! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By a linear transformation of the variable, you can certainly reduce the integrand to a form $t^2\pm1$.

Indeed, let $x=at+b$, then

$$\int\sqrt{3x^2+10x+9}\,dx=a\int \sqrt{3(at+b)^2+10(at+b)+9}\,dt\\
=a\int \sqrt{3a^2t^2+6abt+3b^2+10at+10b+9}\,dt.$$

We cancel the linear term with $$6ab+10a=0$$ and make equal coefficients with $$3a^2=\pm(3b^2+10b+9).$$ This yields, using the positive sign,

$$b=-\frac53,\\a=\dfrac{\sqrt2}3.$$

With these coefficients,

$$\int\sqrt{3x^2+10x+9}\,dx=\frac2{3\sqrt3}\int\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt.$$

Now the integrand $\sqrt{t^2+1}$ can be compared to the identity $\cosh u=\sqrt{\sinh^2u+1}$, and we use $t=\sinh u$ to get

$$\int\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt=\int\cosh u\cosh u\,du=\int\cos^2u\,du.$$

Using the (hyperbolic) trigonometric identity

$$\cosh^2u=\frac{\cosh2u+1}2,$$ the rest is easy.